# kafka failed to update metadata from Java Code

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

i am running a Java Producer code. However, i get the below error :

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Here, is the snippet of my producer class :

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

import pojo.JsonToPojo;

public class KafkaSender {

    public void sendtoKafka(List<JsonToPojo> data) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "0.0.0.0:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaExampleProducer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 5);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 80554432);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
        Producer<String, JsonToPojo> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, JsonToPojo>(props);
        TestCallback callback = new TestCallback();

        for (JsonToPojo toKafka : data) {

            ProducerRecord<String, JsonToPojo> record = new ProducerRecord<String, JsonToPojo>("dontknow", toKafka.group_city.toString(), toKafka);

            // RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();
            // System.out.println("Hey" + metadata.topic());

            producer.send(record, callback);
        }
        producer.close();
    }

    private static class TestCallback implements Callback {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
            if (e != null) {
                System.out.println("Error while producing message to topic :" + recordMetadata);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } else {
                String message = String.format("sent message to topic:%s partition:%s  offset:%s",
                        recordMetadata.topic(), recordMetadata.partition(), recordMetadata.offset());
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using kafka 0.9  version on a MapR cluster. Right now, there is just one broker which is running. I dont get any error apart from the one i have posted above. I have played with the server.properties file by changing a few parameters, but nothing seem to work.

Comment: I fixed this problem by using a custom serializer. Since, i was using JSON as the data format, i needed a JSON serialiser in the Kafka configs. Hope, this helps someone facing the same problem

Comment: why does serializer solve it? reduce the size of the json?

Comment: Basically, when the data is written via Kafka it is an "object". This object if read by Kafka Consumer, wont be understood. Hence, we need an interface which converts this object into a stream of bytes which can be read and understood by a Kafka Consumer